# Подскажите пожалуйста по касперскому ))

Tags: windows, kaspersky

На сервере крутиться Касперский секьюрити центр 11 .Стоит задача перенести его(вместе с политиками и задачами) на другой сервер и установить версию 12. Подскажите как это сделать пошагово со скринами так как это никогда не делала.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164310/как-перенести-касперский-секьюрити-центр-на-другой-сервак-если-можно-пошагово